# Outputting Chinese char instead of numbers? Objective C

Tags: objective-c

What it should do: Take the inputted string group all the numbers and print out every time a new character is appended to the NSMutableString number. Then if the current char is not a number it checks if its + or x, or *, -. If it is one of those then it appends that to an array and prints it out.

What its doing: Outputting chinese

```
`Please enter math: 12+56x45
2012-05-02 23:52:06.538 CALC[1921:403] 퀱 
2012-05-02 23:52:06.541 CALC[1921:403] 퀱퀲 
2012-05-02 23:52:06.542 CALC[1921:403] running array (
"+"
)
2012-05-02 23:52:06.543 CALC[1921:403] 퀱퀲퀵  
2012-05-02 23:52:06.544 CALC[1921:403] 퀱퀲퀵퀶 
2012-05-02 23:52:06.544 CALC[1921:403] 퀱퀲퀵퀶큸 
2012-05-02 23:52:06.545 CALC[1921:403] 퀱퀲퀵퀶큸퀴 
2012-05-02 23:52:06.546 CALC[1921:403] 퀱퀲퀵퀶큸퀴퀵`
```

Issue: I believe it has to do with the unichar `char current = [InputString characterAtIndex:i];` however when i run the code without the `else if` part it works properly. As you can see though the number of characters that are part of the string are the expected number, the issue seems to be they are in the wrong language.

My code:

```
int main ()
{
    char userInput[99];
    NSMutableString *number = [NSMutableString string];
    int i;

    printf( "Please enter math: " );

    scanf( "%s", userInput );
    fpurge( stdin );
    NSString *InputString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:userInput];
    NSMutableArray *broken = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (i=0; i < [InputString length]; i++) {
        char current = [InputString characterAtIndex:i];
        NSString *cur = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , current];
        if (isalnum(current)) {
            [number appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&current length:1]];
            NSLog(@"%@", number);
        }
        else if (current == '+'|| current == 'x'||current == '*'||current == '-') { 
            [broken addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:cur]];
            NSLog(@"running array %@", broken);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually Korean Hangul not Chinese. http://unicode-table.com/en/D036/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've "converted" the `char` into an `NSString`. Why don't you try to append `cur` to the string you are printing? So change:

```
[number appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&current length:1]]
```

to:

```
[number appendString:cur]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is perhaps a higher-level way of separating your numbers from the operators so you can more easily tackle the math you want to perform...

```
NSString *equation = @"12+56x45";
NSCharacterSet *operatorCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"+-/x"];
NSCharacterSet *numberCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"1234567890"];

NSArray *numbersOnly = [equation componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: operatorCharacterSet];
NSArray *operatorsOnly = [equation componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: numberCharacterSet];

for (NSString *number in numbersOnly) {
    NSLog(@"%@", number);
}

for (NSString *operator in operatorsOnly) {
    NSLog(@"%@", operator);
}
```

The end bit just logs the numbers and operators out to show you how they are now divided into different arrays.  This is trivializing your task a bit but if you assume the first data in your equation to be a number you can simply traverse the two arrays in tandem and carry out the math.